# JAX RS ExceptionMapper is not used when doing StreamingOutput

Tags: java, jersey, streaming, jax-rs

I have an exception mapper in JAX-RS application (Jersey 1.19):

```
public class IllegalArgumentExceptionMapper
    implements ExceptionMapper<IllegalArgumentException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Response.Status status = Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST;
    return Response.status(status).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
  }
}
```

And it works correctly (the client will get HTTP status 400) in this case:

```
@GET
@Path("/test1")
public String test2() {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception 1");
}
```

But if I do streaming output like that:

```
@GET
@Path("/test2")
public String test2() {
  return new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream output) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("exception 2");
    }
  };
}
```

Then the exception mapper is not used, and client gets HTTP status 500. So how can I force it to use exception mapper?

Comment: Works fine for me, aside from the fact your code doesn't compile, and you never actually throw the exception

Comment: @peeskillet Oh sorry, I added the missing "throw" in the code sample in question. But I actually tested with correct code, and the mapper isn't used, so can you tell me which implementation do you use, also Jersey 1.19?

Comment: @WojciechGdela were you able to sort this out ? If so, how?

Comment: I did workaround: Instead of `IllegalArgumentException` I'm throwing directly `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` with the appriopriate status code and message.